# TextBox FontFamilyBinding

Tags: c#, wpf

```
private System.Windows.Media.FontFamily fontfamily;
public System.Windows.Media.FontFamily FontFamily
{
    get
    {
        return this.fontfamily;
    }
    set
    {
        this.fontfamily = value;
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FontFamily"));
    }
}

<ComboBox Height="20"  SelectedValue="{Binding TopPanelViewModel.FontFamily,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" Name="Type_Font"   Width="120" Margin="20,0,10,0">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding .}" Text="{Binding Source}" FontSize="15"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <ComboBox.ToolTip>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LangiageViewModel.CurrentToolTips[25]}"></TextBlock>
                                </ComboBox.ToolTip>
                            </ComboBox>
  <TextBox Style="{StaticResource HardBox}" Background="Transparent"  TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="TextBoxInsertText" 
                                FontFamily="{Binding TopPanelViewModel.FontFamily,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                             AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                             KeyUp="TextBoxInsertText_KeyDown" AllowDrop="True" IsUndoEnabled="True"
                         Visibility="{Binding VisibilityPropertiesViewModel.Instance.InsertTextVisibility,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                    </TextBox>'
```

When combo box selected item is changed, the text box family doesn't change. The property works correctly, but the textbox fontfamily doesn't. The combobox and textbox are in different usercontrols.

Answer (score 0):

Change this your `FontFamily` binding in your `TextBox`

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource HardBox}" Background="Transparent"  
  TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="TextBoxInsertText" 
  FontFamily="{Binding ElementName="FontFamilyComboBox",Path=SelectedItem}" 
  AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
  KeyUp="TextBoxInsertText_KeyDown" AllowDrop="True" IsUndoEnabled="True"
  Visibility="{Binding VisibilityPropertiesViewModel.Instance.InsertTextVisibility,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
```

And add a `Name` value to your `ComboBox`

```
<ComboBox Height="20" x:Name="FontFamilyComboBox"  SelectedValue="{Binding TopPanelViewModel.FontFamily,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
       ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}" Name="Type_Font"   Width="120" Margin="20,0,10,0">
          <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <TextBlock FontFamily="{Binding .}" Text="{Binding Source}" FontSize="15"/>
             </DataTemplate>
          </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <ComboBox.ToolTip>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding LangiageViewModel.CurrentToolTips[25]}"></TextBlock>
          </ComboBox.ToolTip>
</ComboBox>
```